# button submits rails form two times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

With rails code:

```
= button_to "-", availability_time_span_path(ts) ,:method  =>  :delete, :remote  =>  true
```

I generate html form, which should be posted via ajax:

```
<form action="/availability_time_spans/175" class="button_to" data-remote="true" method="post">
  <div>
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete">
    <input type="submit" value="-">           
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="n962qRxizeXeoEwWYv2AlMfT4nKxxp9ITUxm5wp1nZo=">
  </div>
</form>
```

When I click on the submit button it is posted twice.
Once as: text/javascript from jquery.js:8417
, second time as: text/html from Other

Comment: use <input type="button" value="-"> and see if it works

Comment: What rails code should I use to generate this? If I just paste the already generated html form and set the type to "button", the form is not submitted at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SOLVED

Problem was I previously inject code using ajax, but renderer response with layout, so the whole jquery was initialized for the second time.

```
respond_with @ra
```

If I render response to ajax call with no layout, then it is fine.

```
respond_with @ra, :layout => false
```

Answer (score 0):

This could happen for a couple of reasons

1. You might have the Javascript cached in your browser. Try clearing your cache or opening the page up in a different browser.
2. You might be serving up precompiled assets. Make sure you have `config.serve_static_assets = false` in your config file.

Comment: I think this is the right direction since in web inspector it shows me jquery.js:2678 and undefined:2678 as event listeners to all events. It could be that jquery is loaded or initialized twice. Clearing cache did not help and config.serve_static_assets is set to false.